# How to convert this input.json code into output.json using python3?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing, bots

I have to convert this input.json code to output response using python.
I am having a problem in creating the output dictionary in python 3.
Please help me I am a newbie in python. Thanks in advance.

**Input.json**

```
{
"function":"sample-text-function",
"questions":[
    {
        "instruction":"Hello! I'm Elth. I'm your personal assistant."
    },
    {
        "text":"Before starting please tell me your first name",
        "var":"first_name"
    },
    {
        "text":"Please tell me your last name",
        "var":"last_name"
    },
    {
        "text":"And your gender?",
        "options":[
            "Male",
            "female"
        ],
        "var":"gender"
    },
    {
        "text":"May I know your age?",
        "var":"age"
    },
    {
        "conditions":[
            [
                "age.isdigit() == False"
            ]
        ],
        "text":"I couldn't quite get how that response can be your age :/ Please enter your valid age.",
        "var":"age"
    },
    {
        "instruction":"Congratulations! Registration Successful."
    }
]
```

}

**Output.json**

```
    {
  "stage1": {
    "Bot Says": [
      {
        "message": {
          "text": "Hello! I'm Elth. I'm your personal assistant."
        }
      },
      {
        "message": {
          "text": "Before starting please tell me your first name"
        }
      }
    ],
    "User Says": "Srinath"
  },
  "stage2": {
    "Bot Says": [
      {
        "message": {
          "text": "Before starting please tell me your last name"
        }
      }
    ],
    "User Says": "Akula",

  },
  "stage3": {
    "Bot Says": [
      {
        "message": {
          "text": "And your gender?",
          "quick_replies": [
            {
              "content_type": "text",
              "title": "Male",
              "payload": "male"
            },
            {
              "content_type": "text",
              "title": "Female",
              "payload": "female"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "User Says": "Male"
  },
  "stage4": {
    "Bot Says": [
      {
        "message": {
          "text": "May I know your age?"
        }
      }
    ],
    "User Says": "what's your age?"
  },
  "stage5": {
    "Bot Says": [
      {
        "message": {
          "text": "I couldn't quite get how that response can be your age :/ 
Please enter your valid age."
        }
      }
    ],
    "User Says": "31 yrs"
  },
  "stage6": {
    "Bot Says": [
      {
        "message": {
          "text": "Congratulations! Registration Successful."
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**My code so far**

I am just trying to insert one value in the output dictionary for example, and getting error

```
import json
from pprint import pprint
from collection import

with open('assignment_1_input_1.json') as f:
    data=json.load(f)
output=dict(dict(list(dict(dict()))))

output['stage1']['Bot Says'][0]['message']['text']=data['questions'][0]['instruction']

print(output)
```

**Error I am Getting**

```
line 11, in <module>
output['stage1']['Bot Says'][0]['message']['text']=data['questions'][0]['instruction']
KeyError: 'stage1'
```

Comment: A KeyError generally means the key doesn't exist.

Comment: Rather than numbered stage keys, I would suggest a format like `{stages: [ {"bot": [], "user": ""}, {"bot": [], "user": ""}]}`

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
output=dict(dict(list(dict(dict()))))
```

Actually just creates an empty dict without any subfields, and is equivalent to

```
output = {}
```

You have to declare each subfield separately before going a level deeper. In fact,

```
output['stage1'] = {}
```

works, while:

```
output['stage1']['Bot Says'] = {}
```

does not.

I suggest you initialize the dict and each subdict with the keys you need such as:

```
 output = {}
 quick_reply = {'content_type': None, 'title': None, 'payload': None}
 message = {'quick_replies': [], 'text': None}
 bot_says = {'message': message}
 user_says = {'User Says': None}

 n_stages = 4
 for n in range(1, n_stages):
     stage_name = 'stage' + str(n)
     output[stage_name] = {'Bot says': [bot_says], 'User Says': None}}
```

And then you fill it in as you wish.

**Output:**

```
{'stage1': {'Bot Says': [{'message': {'quick_replies': [], 'text': None}}], 'User Says': None},
'stage2': {'Bot Says': [{'message': {'quick_replies': [], 'text': None}}], 'User Says': None},
'stage3': {'Bot Says': [{'message': {'quick_replies': [], 'text': None}}], 'User Says': None}}
```

Comment: Why 'bot Says' occours twice in your output ? as per output.json 'bot says' is a list of dictionay. But as per your output bot says is dictionary of dictionary? Thanks for help.@michetonu

Comment: Small mistake for the bot says twice, corrected! As per the list of dictionary, you can just make a small iteration and append bot_says as many times as you want depending on the stage

Comment: @Nishantkumar edited the answer to make Bot says a list of dicts – you can then append a message by: output['stage1']['Bot Says'].append(message_to_append)